# Set variable to part of a SQL statement and use in a CASE WHEN scenario

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

**Synopsis:**

Is it possible to create variables in a stored procedure that contain SQL statements and then reference those statements in a CASE WHEN statement later?

For example:

```
SET @Condition1 = (columnA = columnB AND columnC = 'hello')
SET @Function1 = (columnC + ' and ' + columnA + ' ' + columnB)

SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC, CASE WHEN @Condition1 THEN @Function1 END AS columnD
FROM SampleTable
```

**Full Description:**

I'm working on a stored procedure that will be used in SSRS to display a mailing list table. The initial data looks something like this:

```
Salute    |    first_name    |    last_name    |    Salute2    |    firstname2    |    lastname2
Mr              John               Doe               Mrs               Jane            Doe
Dr              Steve              Smith             Mrs               Steph           Smithington
Mrs             Jill               Hill              Mr                Jack            Hill
```

Ultimately there are about 30 combinations of salutations, (Mr and Mrs, Mrs and Mr, Dr and Dr, etc). I need to create 2 new columns, `FormalAddressee` and `FormalSalutation` that formats the data based on the combination of salutation seen. Here's an example of the end result, please note that the original columns will still exist, I'm just not building out the table for the sake of brevity:

```
Sal|FN|LN|Sal2|FN2|LN2|        FormalAddressee                       |        FormalSalutation        
                           Mr and Mrs John Doe                               Mr John Doe
                           Dr Steve Smith and Mrs. Steph Smithington   Dr Steve Smith and Mrs. Steph Smithington
                           Mr. and Mrs. Jack Hill                            Mr Jack Hill
```

What I was originally starting with was a massive CASE WHEN statement that looked like this, repeated 30 times to cover each salutation combination for `FormalAddressee` and then again for `FormalSalutation` because the THEN part of the statement is different for the 2 columns:

```
WHEN mem.salute = 'Mrs.' AND mem.salute2 = 'Mr.' AND dbo.Proper(mem.last_name) = dbo.Proper(lastname2) 
                     THEN (mem.salute2 + ' and ' + mem.salute + ' ' + dbo.Proper(firstname2) + ' ' + dbo.Proper(lastname2)) ... etc etc END AS FormalAddressee
```

This becomes difficult to manage, especially if new salutation combinations are added (and I'm already aware of an impending new set). Because the `THEN` part of the statements are repeated, meaning the same formatting formula can be used for multiple salutation combinations, I was hoping to set this up as a series of variables to at least make it all a little cleaner and simpler to modify.

This is the example for the `FormalAddressee` info, it would be similar for the `FormalSalutation` info:

```
DECLARE @FA1 nvarchar(300)
DECLARE @FA2 nvarchar(300)
...
DECLARE @FA10 nvarchar(300)

SET @FA1 = (salute2 + ' and ' + salute + ' ' + dbo.Proper(firstname2) + ' ' + dbo.Proper(lastname2))
SET @FA2 = (salute + ' and ' + salute2 + ' ' + dbo.Proper(first_name) + ' ' + dbo.Proper(last_name))
...
SET @FA10 = (dbo.Proper(first_name) + ' ' + dbo.Proper(last_name))

CREATE TABLE #AddressTable
([columns set up here])
INSERT INTO #AddressTable SELECT [existing columns],
CASE WHEN...END AS FormalAddressee,
CASE WHEN...END AS FormalSalutation
FROM AddressDataTable
```

I'm then building out my temp table with the broken out data as seen in the top table above, and creating the new columns and trying to pull the `@FA` variables into the `THEN` part of the `CASE WHEN` statement, but to no avail, and frankly I wasn't optimistic that this would work.

```
CASE  WHEN mem.salute = 'Mrs.' AND mem.salute2 = 'Mr.' AND dbo.Proper(mem.last_name) = dbo.Proper(lastname2) 
    THEN @FA1
```

When I go to execute the SP creation, I get a series of errors stating `The multi-part identifier "salute2" could not be bound` for every line of the `SET` statements. I understand why I get this error, so I tried to convert it to a string, surrounded by single quotes and adding more single quotes to accommodate the internal single quotes, but then my end results just display the string rather than taking the data and combining it for the proper end result.

I'd like to be able to set the salutation combinations as variables as well, as I may be requested to create 6 or 7 columns that format based on the combo seen, so it'd be super sweet to end up with:

```
CASE WHEN @SalCombo1 THEN @FA1 ... END AS FormalAddressee,
CASE WHEN @SalCombo1 THEN @FS1 ... END AS FormalSalutation
```

Am I really over-complicating this and trying to do something that's just not reasonable as opposed to just typing out all of the full `CASE WHEN` statements? I'm fine with doing that, and I probably could have finished it in the time it's taken to research this and ultimately post here on SO, but I feel like there must be a better way that will serve me and my successors more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing all of this in variables, what if you used another intermediate temporary table (or table variable)? If I understand your question correctly, the problem here is that depending the order of fields, you want to be able to re-organize your data. So instead of trying to store that in variables, why not move the data into a re-organized intermediate table?

Here's an attempt based on your example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Intermediate (
  salute1 [datatype],
  salute2 [datatype],
  first1 [datatype],
  first2 [datatype],
  last1 [datatype],
  last2 [datatype]
);

/* @FA1 */ 
INSERT INTO #Intermediate (salute1, salute2, first1, last1)
SELECT salute2, salute, dbo.Proper(firstname2), dbo.Proper(lastname2)
FROM [table]
WHERE mem.salute = 'Mrs.' AND mem.salute2 = 'Mr.' AND dbo.Proper(mem.last_name) = dbo.Proper(lastname2);

/* @FA2 */
INSERT INTO #Intermediate (salute1, salute2, first1, last1)
SELECT salute, salute2, dbo.Proper(first_name), dbo.Proper(last_name)
FROM [table]
WHERE [criteria]

/* @FA10 */
INSERT INTO #Intermediate (first1, last1)
SELECT dbo.Proper(first_name), dbo.Proper(last_name)
```

Then, you have a nicely arranged table, from which you can probably use a single statement to move things into your second temporary table. You won't need to worry about accounting for data being in the wrong fields, because you've already rearranged.

The below is just an example; it's probably not the complete logic you'd need.

```
CREATE TABLE #AddressTable
([columns set up here])

INSERT INTO #AddressTable 
SELECT COALESCE(salute1, '') + COALESCE(' and ' + salute2, '') 
       + first1 + ' ' + last1
       + COALESCE(first2 + ' ' + last2, '')
FROM #Intermediate
```

This is still a mess, but I'm not sure you can avoid a mess with the logic you need. At least it's a bit cleaner than trying to track everything with a different variable.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response! That's an interesting approach that I hadn't even considered. It still seems pretty messy, although using an SP rather than a view at least allows me to use line breaks, tabs and notes to my advantage. I'll give this a shot (it's going to take a while to get it built out properly) and report back. I'd still like to know if I can do what my synopsis asks; Is there a way to use variables with SQL statements within CASE WHEN? Thanks again

Comment: @BobbyScon The only way to do that, AFAIK, is even messier -- use variables to build dynamic SQL statements, and then execute those statements at the end of your procedure.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was fearing. I've done that before for much simpler setups. I was just holding out hope that there was some magic I wasn't aware of that could make this work ;-)